Inlining awaits from different threads in SwiftUI
Here is a code snippet from my SwiftUI ViewModel:
@Published var data: Data
@Published var showingAlert = false
    
func fetchData() {
    Task {
        let result = await NetworkManager.fetchData(),
        await updateUI(with: result)
    }
}
    
@MainActor
private func updateUI(with result: Result<Data, Error>) {
    do {
        data = try result.get()
    } catch {
        showingAlert = true
    }
}

I'm not sure if this is the idiomatic approach (I'm relatively new to SwiftUI) but it works great.
My question is:
Can we get rid of one "await" by merging the lines into a single one?
await updateUI(with: NetworkManager.fetchData())

Is this code equivalent to the previous one?
Most importantly, I need the network call to run on a background thread while the UI updates are performed on the main thread. Is this still the case here?
How can it be proven? (you know, in GPT era everything should be fact checked )

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model and use .task to call your Controller struct that has async funcs. Pass it params and return results, both of these can be states.

Yes, these are equivalent. From the Swift Evolution proposal:

Consider the following example:
// func redirectURL(for url: URL) async -> URL { ... }
// func dataTask(with: URL) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) { ... }

let newURL = await server.redirectURL(for: url)
let (data, response) = try await session.dataTask(with: newURL)

In this code example, a task suspension may happen during the calls to
redirectURL(for:) and dataTask(with:) because they are async
functions. Thus, both call expressions must be contained within some
await expression, because each call contains a potential suspension
point. An await operand may contain more than one potential
suspension point. For example, we can use one await to cover both
potential suspension points from our example by rewriting it as:
let (data, response) = try await session.dataTask(with: server.redirectURL(for: url))

The await has no additional semantics; like try, it merely marks
that an asynchronous call is being made.

As long as NetworkManager.fetchData() is not isolated to the main actor, it will run on a non-main thread, by the cooperative thread pool. Even if it is isolated to the main actor, you are probably using URLSession APIs in its implementation, which are not isolated.
You can call MainActor.shared.assertIsolated() in NetworkManager.fetchData() to "prove" this. If this method crashes, then you are not on the main actor.

It seems like you are using an ObservableObject for this. There is no need for an ObservableObject just for this async operation. You can move everything into your View.
@State var data: Data?
@State var showingAlert = false
    
// @MainActor // in iOS 18, the 'View' protocol is entirely isolated to the MainActor, so this will be redundant
private func updateUI(with result: Result<Data, Error>) {
    do {
        data = try result.get()
    } catch {
        showingAlert = true
    }
}

func fetchData() async {
    let result = await NetworkManager.fetchData(),
    // similarly for the 'await' here. You don't need it in iOS 18
    /*await*/ updateUI(with: result)
}

You can then call this in a .task { ... } or task(id: something) { ... } modifier, which cancels the task if the view disappears. Right now your ObservableObject does not handle cancellation of the top level Task you created.

Yes, you're right, it could be moved to a View just like you suggested. But what about "MVC: Massive View Controller"-like issue? The whole point of ViewModels (as far as I understand) is to split code into two files.

By the way, in your latest code snippet. Don't we need to wrap the body of "func fetchData() async" into Task {} (in order to make it executes on a background thread)?

@Roman SwiftUI Views are already view models. They are not the "views" of MVVM. Views are not the things that you see on screen. You provide SwiftUI with Views, which are view models from which SwiftUI creates the actual views. You can still avoid having e a massive View struct. View structs are very easily composable, and you can easily divide your code up into smaller Views and ViewModifiers.

Or do you mean that as long as something is not explicitly isolated to the main actor, it will always run on a non-main thread by default? If so, then it's totally new piece of knowledge for me

@Roman Well, things can be implicitly isolated to the main actor too :) In iOS 18+, by conforming to the main actor isolated View protocol, all methods in a View struct are implicitly isolated, unless you mark them as nonisolated. But yeah, you got the spirit. Nonisolated methods run on the cooperative thread pool, not the main thread.
